# Как правильно делать запросы на backend в nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, backend, nuxt.js

Как создать запросы из компонентов (components) к API в фреймворке Nuxt.js?

Backend работает по протоколу `http`. Если можете, покажите пример с использованием `store`, но можно и без него.

Попробовал использовать `nuxtServerInit` и запрос делаеться, данные получаю но не могу дальше передать их из `nuxtServerInit` в компонент чтобы их показывать. 
Предпологаю что `nuxtServerInit` не для этого был придуман.

`AsyncData` работает только с компонентами из `pages`.

Нужно получить категорий и отправить их в sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

```
 async nuxtServerInit({ dispatch }) {
    await dispatch('core/load')
 }
```

в самом 'core/load' ложите данные в стор

Comment: а можно подробнее? как выглядит весь store?